# URLSession: TLS ticket does not fit

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, urlsession

When I get a very large response using URLSession, I am getting this warning:

```
[quic] quic_crypto_session_state_serialize [C3.1.1:2] [-4b5609327fb472a4] TLS ticket does not fit (6817 > 6144)
```

Maximum TLS record size is 16 KB, but here we can see only 6 KB.
Maybe there is way to increase TLS ticket size?

Comment: All you can configure is in [URLSessionConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration), and I don't think it has the parameters you are talking about. Before going into a rabbit hole of considering such a deep change... This is not a common error though, while downloading 16k is _very_ common. So it must be something you are doing that is causing it.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a fix for this issue? Encountering the same with the Google Maps API

Comment: @smbrmoyo sadly, no

Comment: After about 5 months, did you find anything useful?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanHasanato sadly, no

Comment: @Dewerro I was getting this error when using a shared API in a KMP (Kotlin Multiplatform) project for the iOS and because I couldn't find a solution I'm currently building the iOS on pure Swift with no shared API

Comment: @AbdulrahmanHasanato I faced this problem using urlsession in pure swift